# Encrypt Microsoft Excel with password using office js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm creating an Excel add-in using office js. I want to encrypt excel with a password using office js.
I know how to do this using macro but I need to do this using office js only.
The below code only protect the structure but does not ask for a password when we open the excel.

```
let password = await passwordHandler();
passwordHelper(password);
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let workbook = context.workbook;
    workbook.load("protection/protected");

    await context.sync();

    if (!workbook.protection.protected) {
        workbook.protection.protect(password);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Arif for your question, I am sorry office.js currently do not provide API for the password protection in file level, because Excel Online does not support Password feature. When the workbook encrypted in win32, and Excel online cannot open it. So we will support after Excel Online support password feature.

You could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature for Excel online at
 https://officespdev.uservoice.com/